# How to check if socket connection is working and buffering or is the request incorrect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have been trying to figure this out and can't seem to wrap my head around it.

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server = '192.168.1.7'
port = 8000
buffer_size = 4096


request = '1|gkdgdfg49|sdfsdfsd*|sdsfsf*|'+server
request = request.encode()
s.connect((server,port))

s.send(request)
x = s.recv(buffer_size)
```

The documentation for the server side is:

https://www.sharekhan.com/Upload/General/TradeTigerAPIForClient.pdf

The `log` of `api server` shows:

```
[I]  "API Client Socket Connected with error Code=0"2018-09-22                               16:07:23.555+05:30  
[I]  "Hurraay You have Connected."2018-09-22 16:07:23.555+05:30  
[I]  "Received Bytes Count = 49 Data Length = 1801944113 Thread State = Background, WaitSleepJoin , Queue Count = 0"2018-09-22 16:07:23.555+05:30  
[I]  "API Client Request Data Length 1801944113 bytes needs to read"
     2018-09-22 16:08:21.984+05:30  
[I]  "Received Bytes Count = 49 Data Length = 1801944113 Thread State =        Background, WaitSleepJoin , Queue Count = 0"
  2018-09-22 16:08:21.984+05:30  
[I]  "API Client Request Data Length 1801944113 bytes needs to read"|Reserved = |
```

Is the `request` correct? Is the `data` being transferred?

If I rerun

```
s.send(request)
x = s.recv(buffer_size)
```

Nothing happens. The interpreter is stuck at running the above two lines.

I would appreciate any help. Very new to `sockets and the documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: 1801944113 bytes is a lot of data. Are you sure it doesn't just take long?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it might take a while, just wondering how a log in request gets that much data. Any way to check if the socket is receiving/reading the data? I left it alone for almost 20 mins and still command kept running. When I run the whole block of code it completes as soon as I press enter. I get the feeling the `request` is wrong somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I pointed out in your other question, this is a binary protocol.

You're sending it ASCII text. Note that big number (1801944113), when interpreted as text, is equal to `'kg|1'`. This is (the big-endian ordering of) the first four characters you sent it. In other words, it's taken the first four bytes you sent it, interpreted them as a binary value, and is now using it as the message length value -- which is obviously all wrong.

You need to use the python `struct` module's `pack` and `unpack` methods to encode and decode binary values to build up your buffer.

That would look something like this:

```
import struct

trans_code = 1 # LOGIN
login_id = b'MyName'
mpassword = b'MyPass'
tpassword = b'MyTradingPass'
my_ip = b'192.168.1.31'      # No idea what the point of this is
reserved = b''

msg_length = 196
msg_buffer = struct.pack("!IH30s20s20s20s100s", msg_length, trans_code,
                         login_id, mpassword, tpassword, my_ip, reserved)
assert len(msg_buffer) == msg_length

print("Login request to send '{}'".format(msg_buffer))
```

You will need to learn to use the `struct` module. It's well-specified in the python documentation.

Your results (in particular that big number) establish that the server is expecting numeric fields to be encoded in big-endian byte order (*AKA* "network byte order").

Comment: Thanks, sorry for taking up so much of your time. I need to read and understand the `struct` module and how encoding changes things. I tried it a bit and failed misreably.